# Do TypeScript mixins not support properties?

Tags: typescript, properties, mixins

I was attempting today to make a complicated class hierarchy that would normally require multiple inheritance in certain other languages, but with mixins in TypeScript, I thought I had a fairly straightforward way of modeling it — until I arrived at the compiler being highly unhappy at everything to do with properties inside mixins.

I started with code that looked like this:

```js
interface IFoo {
    get foo(): boolean;
    set foo(value: boolean);
}

class FooBase implements IFoo {
    get foo(): boolean { return true; }
    set foo(value: boolean) { }
}
```

— which is fine.  I then attempted to turn `FooBase` into a mixin to pull it out of the inheritance chain:

```js
function FooMixin<T>(base: T): IFoo & T {
    return class FooMixin extends T implements IFoo {
        get foo(): boolean { return true; }
        set foo(value: boolean) { }
    }
}
```

The body of the class is identical; only the declaration changed slightly.  But the compiler really doesn't like this mixin, complaining that

```
Type 'typeof FooMixin' is not assignable to type 'IFoo & T'.
  Property 'foo' is missing in type 'typeof FooMixin' but required in type 'IFoo'.
```

I stripped it down even further, and still got the same result:

```js
function FooMixin(): IFoo {
    return class extends T implements IFoo {
        get foo(): boolean { return true; }
        set foo(value: boolean) { }
    }
}
```

```
Property 'foo' is missing in type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' but required in type 'IFoo'.
```

Clearly, it knew that `foo` existed as a property when the class wasn't a mixin, but the type prover seems not to have realized that `get foo()` exists on the mixin class at all.

This seems like a minimal, complete, verifiable example; so am I doing something really wrong here, or is the TypeScript compiler buggy around mixins and properties?

I'm using TypeScript 4.9.4, which appears to be the latest version as of this writing.

Comment: I think you meant to do this? https://tsplay.dev/NDD14N

Comment: @vera Broken link? I get a blank web page when I click it.

Comment: Not for me. It redirects to a playground... Anyways, you should have a generic constraint on `T`: `function FooMixin<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(base: T) {`, and then you should be extending `base` in the function body, not `T`, since `T` is a type parameter and not an actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell TS that `T` must be a constructor, so that you can then extend `base`. You don't need to annotate the return type as TS can infer it for you (and it's indeed very complicated):

```
interface IFoo {
    get foo(): boolean;
    set foo(value: boolean);
}

function FooMixin<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(base: T) {
    return class FooMixin extends base implements IFoo {
        get foo(): boolean { return true; }
        set foo(value: boolean) { }
    }
}

class Bar {
    bar = 0
}

const FooBar = FooMixin(Bar);

new FooBar().foo // ok
new FooBar().bar // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8CwAUMicgOYRjIzYAUAlAFzIBG2ANhHCANxGnIAzpWp0AbnHYBXCMzaZO3en0IBfIkRhSQCMMEwhkWTAFlgAD1AAeACrII5yCAAmg5CAgB3ZLQB0-uCgyQWZuAE8AbQBdemQAXgA+ZHCE2hY4YWYbWIJiUihKKShDBHYMt2MzS0MHJ1dWDJRgAFsAB05miHA3DGw8fgFSCioaTAY5Di5DXGQCsCLDMCgZHmR1PMGhEVHaCWlZVkmlPDWBknX1olLy5AAhQP6Nhqh45AAGIkvCBANBKmN7i84kZsFVQLRAcoNIQPN4AYEGL5RkRYSDMIDEekoEA)

Comment: That's really hideous syntax, coupled with a really obtuse error message, if not the wrong error message outright. I can understand why there needs to be a class constraint there (and my kingdom for just `where T: class`). But the error message really should be `cannot extend 'base' because it's not a class type`, not `'FooMixin' doesn't have a 'foo' despite clearly having a 'foo'`.

Comment: @SeanWerkema 1/2 ... _"That's really hideous syntax"_ ... of cause it is. And it is due to the `FooMixin` function which is not a mixin but a factory-function which ad-hoc creates always a newly implemented class (thus the class name does not even matter) which extends the passed `base` class. One never leaves inheritance, one only obfuscates the factories intermediate step of the dynamic sub-classing, which does confuse so many users, (trying to) make them believe they are using a mixin implementation.

Comment: @SeanWerkema 2/2 ... Thus the OP does not need to (quoting the OP) ... _"[attempt] to turn `FooBase` into a mixin to pull it out of the inheritance chain"_. The OP instead could implement a `class` and `extends` based inheritance chain as straightforward as possible with TypeScript and would produce cleaner and less cheating code unless the OP tries real (no inheritance involved)  mixin patterns.

Comment: @PeterSeliger In this case, I had functionality — not just interfaces but actual code — that needed to be glued into lots of different classes, some of which were related, but most of which were not. In C++ or Python, I'd use multiple inheritance. In Ruby, true mixins. In more traditional JS, I'd just make a function that stamps other functions sideways into whichever prototypes need them. But I'm trying to play nice with TypeScript's type system here, and TypeScript doesn't really like this very much.

Comment: @SeanWerkema … I‘m fully aware of all that.